# How to wait for the facebook javascript api response using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want my my postuserWall() function to wait for the FB.api response then it return true or false.but it is not waiting for the response.
How can i get it to wait for the response 
here is my main function which is calling the postuserWall function the alert is showing me `undefined`

```
$('.vacancies_tbl').on('click', '.btn-edit-vacancy', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
         var $this = $(this);                   
         var chcek =  postuserWall();
         alert(chcek);
         if(check){
            window.location = $this.attr('href');
         }                                                              
});
```

Here is my postuserWall function

```
 function postuserWall(){

        var body = 'Usama New Post';
        FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: body }, function(response) {
          if (!response || response.error) {
            console.log(response);
            alert('Error occured');
            return false;
          } else {
            alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
            return true;
          }
        });
    }
```

it is not waiting for the response in the postuserWall function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution (make sure you understand what asynchronous means, it´s very important in JavaScript):

```
$('.vacancies_tbl').on('click', '.btn-edit-vacancy', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);                   
    postUserWall(function(check) {
        alert(check);
        if(check){
            window.location = $this.attr('href');
        }
    });                                                             
}); 

function postUserWall(callback) {
    var body = 'Usama New Post';
    FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', {message: body}, function(response) {
        if (!response || response.error) {
            console.log(response);
            alert('Error occured');
            callback(false);
        } else {
            alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
            callback(true);
        }
    });
}
```

You can also use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), but that´s overkill for just one callback.

Comment: you use a function as parameter. that function can be called anywhere in postUserWall. it´s actually the same as the callback function of the click handler you are already using.